# How do I toggle between divs using a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been working on my first experimental website and for the front page there is a image slide show div section on the page. I have a button in the top right corner to sign in. When the user clicks the sign in button, id like the image slide show to be hidden and a login form to be displayed in its place.

I'm hoping to click this button. (The styling for the button is in a css file connected to the div.)

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="signin">
  <div id="logbutton">
    Sign in
  </div>
</a>
```

I want to toggle between these two

```
<div id="pic">
  <img src="img/header.jpg" id="imgBanner" />
</div>

<div id="logbox" style="display: none;">
  Login form
</div>
```

On clicking the button, this javascript function is/should be run

```
$(function(){
  $('#signin').click(function(){
    $('#pic').toggle();
    $('#logbox').toggle(); 
  });
});
```

I get the feeling I've missed something or I may have miss used this code entirely.

Comment: Easiest solution: Hide all of the `divs` that are toggled, then unhide the one you want.  Putting something like `toggle_div` in the `class` can help to find them easily.

Comment: You work seem fine check it over here http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/uxTTZ/

Comment: You can't place a block element (`<div>`) inside an inline element (`<a>`)

Comment: what's wrong ? it seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/vAk7m/

Comment: "Seems to work" is not good enough in web design.  The browsers "fix" things behind your back and suddenly, the browser is doing something you don't expect and with invalid markup it becomes a horrible pain to track down.  My first rule of any web debugging is 'fix the markup.'

Comment: I think the issue is linking the javascript to the html code. How 'should' you go about this? I may have done that part wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First:
I would do this like this:

```
<script>
 var showLoginForm = false;
 $(function(){
   $('#signin').click(function(){
    $('#pic,#logbox').hide();
    $('#pic').toggle(!showLoginForm);
    $('#logbox').toggle(showLoginForm);
  });
 });
</script>
```

Second:
It's a bad HTML practice put block elements (divs, table, etc.) inside inline elements (a, span, etc).
Remove the  and style  according to your needs, here is an example:

```
<style>
 .linkButton {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
 }
</style>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="signin" class="linkButton">Sign in</a>
```

Comment: Looking at what's happening, the function isn't been called and i'm not exactly sure how it should be called in this case. Is the href="javascript:void(0);" stopping it from running?

Comment: no! href="javascript:void(0);" won't stop onclick function. But, if you want you can use href="#".

also, instead using jQuery onload assign, you can put it in a function, some like toggleForm(){$('#pic...}.. and it call it from <a href="#" ... onlick="toggleForm();" />